# How can you Internationalize Chrome Extension for Cantonese (Hong Kong)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, internationalization, chinese-locale

How can you Internationalize Chrome Extension for Cantonese (Hong Kong)?

[Internationalizing Your App - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/i18n/#choosing-locales-to-support) lists Locale Codes that it says you can localize your app in. But for Chinese it only lists two options: zh_CN Chinese (China) and
zh_TW Chinese (Taiwan)

According to [Internet statistics](https://www.vengaglobal.com/blog/simplified-traditional-chinese-mandarin-cantonese/), both mainland China and Taiwan speak Mandarin, but mainland China uses Simplified characters whereas Taiwan uses Traditional characters.

But what if I want to internationalize the extension for Cantonese (Hong Kong)? Is there a Locale Code that can be used for that? This might include a video using Cantonese language. According to [Internationalizing Your App - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/i18n/#specifying-where-to-publish-your-app) extensions can be listed in Hong Kong.

It seems like this should be possible since Google TTS supports Cantonese (Hong Kong) 粤語  ( 香港 ) and [Google Cloud Speech-to-Text Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages) supports Cantonese using language code: yue-Hant-HK

So could I use locale code yue-Hant-HK in the extension package in the _locales directory to support Cantonese? Or could I use the standard language code for Hong Kong zh-HK to support Cantonese?

Comment: You'll have to use a custom js library.

Comment: @wOxxOm That isn't what I am asking. I want to know if I can use a different locale in the _locales directory then what is listed on the Chrome Developers documentation. I want the Chrome web store listing to display differently for Cantonese speakers in Hong Kong. A library won't help with that.

Comment: Nope, only the locales listed in the documentation are supported.

Comment: @wOxxOm That is too bad. Thank you for the answer.